# Pattern matching in Tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I have somefile.txt, contains lines like:

```
{ abc1 } 1
{ cde1 } 101
{ fgh1 } 1
{ ijk1 } 2
```

its a huge file, i wanted to find only 1st and 3rd line and count them.

I have tried with regexp and lsearch(converting it to list) by `{\s\}\s1\n}` but its not working. What should I do...?

I have also tried `{\s\}\s1}` but it prints all 4 lines.

Comment: You question is very unclear: what output do you want to see?

Comment: So, you want to sum up 1+1?

Comment: OK, I wanted see only those line which ends with 1(only 1, not even 111,101 or 100) outside the curly brackets. There are millions of lines, I have shown here only four, inside the bracket characters like "",[],/, e.g { a/b"[c] } 1 are also there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** If you dont want to use `regexp` and your inputs line have same format like `{string} number`

```
set fd [open "somefile.txt" r]
while {[gets $fd line] >= 0} {
    if {[lindex $line 1] == 1} {
        puts [lindex $line 1] ;# Prints only 1
        puts $line            ;# Prints Whole Line which has 1 at end
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:** If you want to use `regexp`, then go for `group-capturing` which is `(.*)`

```
set fd [open "somefile.txt" r]
while {[gets $fd line] >= 0} {
    if {[regexp "\{.*\} (.*)" $line match match1]} {
        if {$match1 == 1} {
            puts $line
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 3:** Based on @Peter suggestion on `regexp`

```
set fd [open "somefile.txt" r]
while {[gets $fd line] >= 0} {
    if {[regexp {\d+$} $line match]} {
        if {$match == 1} {
            puts $match ;# Prints only 1
            puts $line  ;# Prints whole line which has 1 at end 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better regexp: `regexp {\d+$} $line match`, then compare `$match` to 1.

Comment: @PeterLewerin for my understanding, your given regexp will find all digits at the end. m i correct ?

Comment: Yes, it finds the longest continous string of digits that is at the end of the searched string.

Comment: Was refering to Solution 1 of Axt_8041

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need to capture the digits at the end of the first and third lines.

Here is a way to achieve that:

```
set s {{ abc1 } 1
{ cde1 } 101
{ fgh1 } 1
{ ijk1 } 2}
set re {^{[^{}]*}\s*(\d+)\s+{[^{}]*}\s*\d+\s+{[^{}]*}\s*(\d+)}
regexp $re $s m g1 g2
set res [expr $g1 + $g2]
puts $res
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/OAJCZu)

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of a string
- `{[^{}]*}` - a `{...}`-like string with no braces inside
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`g1`) capturing 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (can be replaced with `[\r\n]+` if there can be no trailing/leading whitespace before and after)
- `{[^{}]*}\s*\d+\s+{[^{}]*}\s*(\d+)` - see above, just `(\d+)` will create a second variable, `g2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZ5sG7/1)

Answer (score 0):

A problem like this gets around an order or magnitude easier to solve if you don't use regular expressions.

```
package require fileutil

::fileutil::foreachLine line somefile.txt {
    if {[lindex $line end] == 1} {
        puts $line
    }
}
```

This solution looks at each line in the file and checks if the last item is equal to 1. If so, the line is printed.

You could also count them / sum them:

```
set count 0
set sum 0
::fileutil::foreachLine line somefile.txt {
    if {[lindex $line end] == 1} {
        puts $line
        incr count
        incr sum [lindex $line end] ;# yeah, I know, always 1
    }
}
puts "Number of lines: $count"
puts "Sum of items: $sum"
```

If `fileutil` isn't available in your Tcl installation and you can't or don't want to install it, you can use the lower-level core equivalent:

```
set f [open somefile.txt]
while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
    if {[lindex $line end] == 1} {
        puts $line
    }
}
close $f
```

If you absolutely must use a regular expression, in this case you could do this:

```
::fileutil::foreachLine line somefile.txt {
    if {[regexp {\m1$} $line]} {
        puts $line
    }
}
```

This regular expression finds lines that end with the digit 1 in a word by itself (i.e. there are no digits or word characters preceding it).

Documentation: [close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm), [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)

Comment: yes i wanted to print those lines which ends with 1(only 1, not even 111,101 or 100) in the end, I cant use values in bracket coz there are millions of lines and all have different names inside bracket. But there are some lines which ends with 1, I wanted to print those lines only.

Comment: I think ur code will work, but i am not able to use fileutil, I am using tcl on linux machine.Thank you

Comment: @ShivankG: `fileutil` is available on all platforms, but might need to be installed.

Comment: You can use `fileutil` on linux machine. If you are using tclsh 8.5 then its inbuilt.